# Flying Saucer PDF, how do you add an Image that is a link?

Tags: java, velocity, flying-saucer

I am developing a PDF with Flying Saucer via Velocity and I need to show a button that when pressed will point to a URL.

I am currently using a simple anchor tag with an img tag as follows:

```
<a href="$applyUrlsKey.get($cntr)" target="_blank"><img alt="Apply button image" src="images/applyButton_small.gif" title="Apply" /></a>
```

But this simply shows the image on the PDF and am unable to click on it.

So how can I make this imgage clickable?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this problem? I am still unable to make links in flying saucer.

Answer (score 3):

I was faced with the same problem and putting the a-tag to be a block, fixed the problem:

```
<a href="$applyUrlsKey.get($cntr)" style="display: block" target="_blank">
    <img alt="Apply button image" src="images/applyButton_small.gif" title="Apply" />
</a>
```

Hopefully this does the trick for you.

Comment: Did this really solve the issue? I tried it and it did not work - I am unable to solve the issue.

Comment: display: inline-block; text-decoration: none works for me also